# Website, can't read php as code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have developed an website, and I was using just HTML, JS and CSS codes.
The pages are created like www.example.com/**Home**, it means no format...
My website was running well before i put this single line php code in it:

```
<?php include 'PageLoader_ST.php' ?>
```

Here is the code in screenshoot:
[image]

And here is the code read by Browser:

[image]

I am a little confused on how can i make  it work? I don't wan't to use this format `Home.php`, is it possible anyway?

Comment: if you get php code in your browser, then php isn't working on your server properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file that should be parsed as php code, must have the file extension `.php`. There is no way around this.

The url and the real file name on disk must not be the same. Very often (and when you use a framework, almost always) they do not correspond. This is achieved through url rewriting. With an Apache server this is done with a .htaccess file.

You could use it to remove the .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use PHP two things must happen.

1.) PHP must be installed on your server (I'm assuming apache), you can do this by either installing a windows lamp package (like xampp or wamp. installing standalone on a windows server is kinda tricky) Or if you're using a linux environment you can install PHP along with apache by installing the relevant packages.

2.) Your files must have a `.php` extension in order to tell the php engine that the file contains php script and it must be run through the engine to parse the scripting.

This is a design element in PHP and it is intentional.

EDIT: after reading your question again it looks like you're trying to have your homepage be mydomain.com/Home instead of mydomain.com/home.php.

Having a file that doesn't have an extension is not how you do that. Your file needs .php, and when you want to display the home page you need to use Apache rewrite rules in order for you to have the "pretty urls" affect for SEO and readability.

Comment: Nice, my server is still running php but the second thing it means my files must be definitely .php formating :/, anyway thank you..

Comment: If this helped you get the script running, be sure to mark it as accepted :). Also, if you want to still have mydomain.com/Home as your home page while still keeping the .php extension for your script to run, look up on Google for Apache Rewrite Rules and learn how to customize how your server processes URLs. you can still do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the `.php` from being visible if you use a folder structure along with 'index.php' files. Apache will look for a default file called `index` in each directory and use that before any others. For example if folder `Home` contains a file called `index.php`, you can still use the URL `www.example.com/home/` and your site will still work.

This method will also work with a file named `index.html` or others.

NOTE: The `Home` directory can still contain other files that can be linked to but they must be linked to using the URL `www.example.com/home/filename.extension`

Comment: This is a decent work around but will quickly become impractical for larger sites. Apache Rewrites are always better :).

Comment: I completely agree that a rewrite solution would be best. But given by the assumed competency level of the developer I thought a simpler more practical and easier to implement solution might be best here. However if Flamur feels comfortable doing that, the rewrite is what I would advise too

Comment: I agree with everything, of course I learn more from the answers, and I know what an index.php, index.html or index.htm is... How ever thanks for all this informations ^^.